# Solution for three variable Simultaneous Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

I have two Equations :
$$1)\; abc=1$$
$$2)\; a+b+c=1$$

And the constraint that $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers.
I have to prove that there exist no solution for the given constraint.

My attempt:
I substituted $a$ in terms of$ b$ and $c$ in equation 2 
It resulted in a Diophantine equation.
I tried getting constraint for value of $b$ by using the inequality that discriminant of a quadratic must be positive for a real root to exist but the inequality results in a 4th degree equation in $c$.

Comment: From the 2nd equation, it follows that $0<a,b,c<1$. Can the first equation hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AM-GM will help you:
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{abc}$$ which gives $$1\geq 3$$

Answer (score 0):

Since we have inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean

$$1= a+b+c\geq 3\sqrt[3]{xyz} =3$$

we have no solution.